# Can you use CSS to detect if your email HTML is rendering on an iOS vs Android device?

Tags: iphone, android, css, ios, user-agent

I need to show different links (regular url or iOS [Custom URL Scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)) in our email depending on if its being read on an android or iOS device. The workaround is to have a redirect link to figure it out by opening the browser and looking at the User Agent server side, but I'm trying to avoid that to have better user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack it a little by using CSS [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). Consider that [90%+](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) of Android phones can be described with two different screen geometries, then maybe you can get a query that works most of the time.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this just yet but from what I've researched this might be the only possible as-good-as-it-gets solution. Once I get to code it up I'll post my results.